Is there a specific term to distinguish two sides of a quadrilateral opposite to its vertex?
In a quadrilateral, there are two sides that may be called 'opposite' in respect to its vertex.

The red side and the blue side are both opposite to the given vertex. Are there terms to distinguish the red side from the blue side when referencing that red vertex?
In case if not, I suggest pretty good ones:

Direct-opposite (blue): if we go around the quadrilateral clockwise, the first opposite side we meet is blue.
Counter-opposite (red): if we go around the quadrilateral counter-clockwise, the first opposite side we meet is red.


I suggest "forward-opposite" and "backward-opposite", relative to an explicitly specified orientation of the polygon. (Don't assume the reader understands "clockwise" as "forward".) Of course, if the orientation is reflected in vertex labels (eg, $V_0$, $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$), then the sides opposite $V_i$ are simply $V_{i+1}V_{i+2}$ and $V_{i-1}V_{i-2}$, with index arithmetic performed modulo $4$. (I might therefore consider denoting these sides $v_i^+$ and $v_i^-$, but I'd need to weigh my notational needs against the potential of reader confusion, esp since each side gets multiple names.)

The need for such terms is so limited in scope that they would need to be explicitly defined whenever they are used. Then you could refer to them as $O$ and $O'$, or Optimus and Optimus Prime.
